# CSS is overwriting id style by tag style in the same stylesheet

Tags: html, css

According to [Specificity Hierarchy](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) ID style should be over tag style, but on the following code snippet, the opposite is happening!

I expect the table to be blue, but it is red, can anyone explain that?

```css
#body table {
    background: red;
}

#table {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th style="position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background: gray;">something</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>ha</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ha</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ha</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ha</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because an ID + element selector has a higher specificity than just ID alone.

Comment: In a sense, both of your styles are ID-based.  If you remove `#body` from the first style-- or even just `#`-- you'll get what you expect.

Comment: @Terry I expected that **the direct ID on the element** will have higher specificity than **Parent ID + the element tag**, doesn't that make sense?

Comment: You add up all the 'elements' of the selector, so `#body` + `table` versus `#table`. So the calculation is done over the entire selector string, not just the last item.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Specifity [CSS Specifity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) explains it in the section: *How to Calculate Specificity?*

You had for `#body table` the following specificity calculation:
100 + 1 = 101 (ID + element)

For the `#table` you had the following specifity calculation:
100 = 100 (ID)

So `#body table` has the higher specifity (101 > 100). So as a example you can remove the # from the body `body table` than the specifity is 1 + 1 = 2 and lower than `#table` (100).